# Helm3 - invalid checksum digest format while pushing chart to gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

When I try to push a helm chart on a registry I get the following error:

```
Error: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:5baf343aead5ca0a290482a62446500bc92678c991f70f67897c80cc69f7e39b": invalid content digest in response: invalid checksum digest format
```

I try to push on Gitlab, Github (on a personnal existing repository)

I use helm v3.0.0+ge29ce2a

Here the command I use :

1) Login to the registry

```
$ helm registry login -p ${myPassword} -u ${myUsername } ${myRepository}
Login succeeded
```

2) Chart save command

```
$ helm chart save chartName monrepo.gitlab.io/project/chartName:0.3
ref:     monrepo.gitlab.io/project/chartName:0.3
digest:  045670a42277f7d66049e00d17a8d6928398073e9659d7a531dccbd4a990d6ba
size:    1.5 KiB
name:    chartName
version: 0.3
0.3: saved
```

3) Chart push

```
$ helm chart push monrepo.gitlab.io/project/chartName:0.3
Error: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:5baf343aead5ca0a290482a62446500bc92678c991f70f67897c80cc69f7e39b": invalid content digest in response: invalid checksum digest format
```

==== STACK TRACE ====

```
helm.go:76: [debug] invalid checksum digest format
invalid content digest in response
github.com/containerd/containerd/remotes/docker.(*pushWriter).Commit
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/remotes/docker/pusher.go:364
github.com/containerd/containerd/content.Copy
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/content/helpers.go:151
github.com/containerd/containerd/remotes.push
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/remotes/handlers.go:171
github.com/containerd/containerd/remotes.PushHandler.func1
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/remotes/handlers.go:146
github.com/containerd/containerd/remotes.PushContent
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/remotes/handlers.go:216
github.com/deislabs/oras/pkg/oras.Push
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/deislabs/oras@v0.7.0/pkg/oras/push.go:54
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/experimental/registry.(*Client).PushChart
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/internal/experimental/registry/client.go:126
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*ChartPush).Run
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/pkg/action/chart_push.go:43
main.newChartPushCmd.func1
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/chart_push.go:45
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:826
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:914
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:864
main.main
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/helm.go:75
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:5baf343aead5ca0a290482a62446500bc92678c991f70f67897c80cc69f7e39b"
github.com/containerd/containerd/content.Copy
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/content/helpers.go:153
github.com/containerd/containerd/remotes.push
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/remotes/handlers.go:171
github.com/containerd/containerd/remotes.PushHandler.func1
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/remotes/handlers.go:146
github.com/containerd/containerd/remotes.PushContent
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0/remotes/handlers.go:216
github.com/deislabs/oras/pkg/oras.Push
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/deislabs/oras@v0.7.0/pkg/oras/push.go:54
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/experimental/registry.(*Client).PushChart
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/internal/experimental/registry/client.go:126
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*ChartPush).Run
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/pkg/action/chart_push.go:43
main.newChartPushCmd.func1
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/chart_push.go:45
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:826
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:914
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:864
main.main
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/helm.go:75
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
```

Error and Stack trace are the same when I try to push on Github Helm repositry or Gitlab OCI Container Registry.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I got similar type of error, but it was for case sensitivity. I was using uppercase characters like you are.
Also, check your chart versioning. It should be in the format of 1.1.1 (major.minor.patch) or a single numeric value.

This might help.
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/conventions/